# Why rosmake will skip when I set locale?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a language.sh:

```
  export LANG=en_US
  export LC_MESSAGE=en_US.UTF8
```

I have one package which rosmake will show error msg in chinese:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                             
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['rein']                                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rein']                                                                                                
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-205804                                                      
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rein'] to:
  ['rein']                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rein [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesin: 4.9 sec ]                                                                           [ 1 Active 31/32 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 13%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 23%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_py
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 23%] Built target rospack_gensrv
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 37%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_lisp
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 51%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 67%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 67%] Built target rospack_genmsg
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 67%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 69%] Built target detection_displayer
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    [ 72%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rein.dir/src/io/fs_model_storage.o
    /home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/src/io/fs_model_storage.cpp: In member function 「virtual bool rein::FilesystemModelStorage::getModelList(const string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)」:
    /home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/src/io/fs_model_storage.cpp:102:30: 錯誤： 「class boost::filesystem3::directory_entry」 沒具名為 「leaf」 的成員
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rein.dir/src/io/fs_model_storage.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rein.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package rein written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-205804/rein/build_output.log
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rein [FAIL] [ 4.93 seconds ]                                                                                       
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rein. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                     
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] Built 32 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                              
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-205804                                                                           
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$
```

But when I try to run language.sh to change error msg to english version, it will cause rosmake to skip make process:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ chmod +x ~/language.sh 
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ . ~/language.sh 
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                                             
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['rein']                                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rein']                                                                                                
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-205614                                                      
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rein'] to:
  ['rein']                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs                                                                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge                                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                                                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                                                       
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl  No Makefile in package pcl                                                                                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rein [ make ]                                                                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rein [SKIP] No rule to make target None                                                                            
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                        
  [ rosmake ] Built 32 packages with 0 failures.                                                                                              
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120903-205614                                                                           
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$
```

How did that happened?

It made me failed to put English version of error msg.

And it also can't generate any useable binary file.

How to fix it?

Thank you~

===========================

I try just make:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ make
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
    what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
  Makefile:1: /cmake.mk: No such file or directory
  make: *** No rule to make target `/cmake.mk'.  Stop.
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$
```

====================================

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$ locale -a
  locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
  locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
  locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
  C
  C.UTF-8
  POSIX
  en_AG
  en_AG.utf8
  en_AU.utf8
  en_BW.utf8
  en_CA.utf8
  en_DK.utf8
  en_GB.utf8
  en_HK.utf8
  en_IE.utf8
  en_IN
  en_IN.utf8
  en_NG
  en_NG.utf8
  en_NZ.utf8
  en_PH.utf8
  en_SG.utf8
  en_US.utf8
  en_ZA.utf8
  en_ZM
  en_ZM.utf8
  en_ZW.utf8
  zh_CN.utf8
  zh_HK.utf8
  zh_SG.utf8
  zh_TW.utf8
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/perception/recognition/rein$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42887/why-rosmake-will-skip-when-i-set-locale?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-03**:
Interesting.. What does a "make" in the directory result in?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-03**:
I have edited my original post to add `make` result.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-03**:
OK, maybe it's just that you have the locale not installed?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-03**:
What's that means? How to fix it? Thank you~

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-04**:
Can you check the output of locale -a?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-05**:
I have edited my original post to add `locale -a` result.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-05**:
The good thing is, the locale is there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake does some parsing of the stdout to detect if there was no rule to make target.  The string matching is likely screwed up by the different locale.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-12**:
How to fix it? I also couldn't understand what happened.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-09-18**:
Set your locale to en_US.UTF-8 when running rosmake.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-09-19**:
I set export LANG=en_US
export LC_MESSAGE=en_US.UTF-8
But still pass the rosmake.process.